# Unable to create Sqlite db on Samsung tablet on deviceready event

Tags: sfdcmobilesdk-android

Using the salesforce mobile SDK's test app on a Samsung tablet, I get an error when I attempt to create a Sqlite db in the deviceready event.  I tried moving the logic before and after the authenticateUser method.  Oddly, if you kill the app and then re-open it, the database creates without an issue.

The error is "Cannot open database: Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18"

The code is here:

```
/* Wait until cordova is ready to initiate the use of cordova plugins and app launch */
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    console.debug('device is ready');

    var db1;
    try {
        if ((typeof db1) == 'undefined'){
            db1 = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "test db", 1000000);
        }
    }
    catch (ex) {
        alert("Cannot open database: " +ex.toString());
    }
    authenticateUser(showUsersList);

}, false);
```

Comment: HAve you tried the shim mentioned here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2823 ?

Comment: @FrankZ I will give that a try on Monday when I have access to the device again.

Comment: @FrankZ that didn't work.  I'm using Cordova 3.6.4 and it appears that shim does not work for that version.  Namely, _storage is undefined_ is the new error.  So I'm still stuck.